# PromQL sum by label over time

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to sum up a counter metric over time and grouped by the label applied.  I've tried this

```
sum  by  (searchTerm)  (bot_guides_failed_total)
```

but I want to have out in a table form like this:

searchTerm1 : 5

searchTerm2: 1
etc..

I'm new to PromQL so let me know if you need more information form me to help me figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following PromQL query should return the increase of `bot_guides_failed_total` time series over the last hour (see `1h` in square brackets) grouped by `searchTerm` label:

```
sum(increase(bot_guides_failed_total[1h])) by (searchTerm)
```

If this query is used for building a graph in Grafana, then every point on the graph will contain the increase of the `bot_guides_failed_total` metric over the one hour interval ending at this point.

Note that the `increase()` function in Prometheus may return unexpected results when applied to slow-changing counters. This is because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. If you need the expected results from the `increase()` function, then try VictoriaMetrics instead - this is Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function to extract the number of searches in a specific time window. E.g:

```
sum  by  (increase(searchTerm[5m]))  (bot_guides_failed_total)
```

This will give you the number of `searchTerm` grouped by `bot_guides_failed_total` in a 5 minutes time window.